# Kendo UI treeview binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-binding, binding, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I want to make a Kendo `TreeView` that shows all nodes on first load. I'm using the Kendo 'Binding to remote data' sample but it doesn't work correctly. It shows just the first level and the id passed to the controller action is always null.
Please help me.

**View code :**

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
    .Name("treeview")
    .DataTextField("Title")
    .ExpandAll(true)
    .LoadOnDemand(false)
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Read(read => read.Action("Employees", "Follow").Data("addData"))))

 function addData(data) {
    return { id: data.id };
}
```

**Controller code :** (controller `Follow`)

```
public System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult Employees(int? id)
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<FollowType> List =
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<FollowType>();

    if (id.HasValue == true) {
        List = FollowTypeList.FindAll(current => current.ParentId == id);
    } else {
        List = FollowTypeList.FindAll(current => current.ParentId == null);
    }

    System.Collections.Generic.List<Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel> NodeList =
        new System.Collections.Generic.List<Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel>();

    foreach (CommonData.Domain.FollowType item in List)
    {
        NodeList.Add(new Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel() { 
            Id = item.Id.ToString(), 
            Text = item.Title, 
            HasChildren = FollowTypeList.Exists(c => c.Id == item.ParentId) 
        });
    }

    return Json(NodeList, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in your javascript code, the `id` field of data should be `Id` (be careful to the capitalization) :

```
return { id : data.Id };
```